# Android Studio 2.3 stopped finding some files in find Filename (Cmd+Shift+O)

Tags: android-studio

I have been using

```
Android Studio 2.3.3
Build #AI-162.4069837, built on June 6, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

For some reason, recently, it doesn't find files, Java or Kotlin, under a certain subdirectory.

More strange things:

1. It does find files under any other directory
2. If I create a new file, sibling to the files it fails to find, be it Java or Kotlin, Cmd+Shift+O will find them.
3. Double Shift (find all) or find class - finds them
4. I tried to delete .idea, all *.iml and the build folder, and reopen the project. No success.
5. It does find some .puml files. Anything that's not a class file.

Does anybody know what could have happened to Android Studio that its simplest search, find by filename, has gone bad?

**Update**

- Move the subtree to some quarantine folder or a zip
- Then open Android Studio. Let it fail on compilation
- Put the files back

That is not a solution but it does a band-aid fix.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning **Android studio**, not the **project** caches worked.

File -> Invalidate caches/Restart (not sure if that would be enough).

To be 100% sure, do it the manual way: they are in:

```
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio2.3
```

Feel free to kill them all.

Close Android Studio

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio2.3
```

And don't forget to do a wicked grinning before pressing Enter :)

Turn on your Android Studio and: Magic! It's all fixed. You can find your files again.

Note that I suspect it may be a cause of switching versions back and forth. When switching versions, Android Studio has to index a different snapshot of your code along time. It may potentially be a cause for bugs.